# Beaglebone black with DLP2000EVM

Tags: python, linux, beagleboneblack

I am trying to play video using Beaglebone black and DLP2000EVM.

manually I can play a video by enabling I2c. But when I try to play using a python script I am getting an error like this

> debian@beaglebone:/opt/scripts/device/bone/capes/DLPDLCR2000$ python MplayerTest.py
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "MplayerTest.py", line 89, in 
>       main()
>       File "MplayerTest.py", line 59, in main
>       datalog = DataLog(LogDir, Test_name)
>       File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/dlp_lightcrafter/datalog.py", line 77, in **init**
>       IOError: [Errno 13] **Permission denied:** '0524/tmp_header_Video Play Test__Tue__Nov_14_2017__11_19_37__.xls'

the system isn't being allowed to write to the datalog file seems.

anyone, please help me to fix this problem.

thank you.

Comment: execute as sudo: `sudo python MplayerTest.py `

Comment: thank you, it is partially working .....

Comment: thank you, it is partially working ... just BBB desktop is projected. but a video is not playing. could you please help me to fix this issue.
vo: couldn't open the X11 display (:0)!
No protocol specified
[gl] OpenGL 3.x context creation not implemented.
No protocol specified
vo: couldn't open the X11 display (:0)!
No protocol specified
SDL SetVideoMode failed: No video mode large enough for 320x200
[VO_SDL] Couldn't get any acceptable SDL Mode for output.
FATAL: Cannot initialize video driver.
FATAL: Could not initialize video filters (-vf) or video output (-vo).